# How do I speed up the batch of update queries over the table with 2 million rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have around 2 million update queries

```
UPDATE table1 
SET WIN = 'A-9-0-9999-00000-00000-0000' 
WHERE WIN= 'A-0-9-0000-999999-000000'
```

Now I have around 2 millions update queries which I paste in SQL window and run at once but it's taking around 1 hour for each system (I have same db over different servers).

The `table1` itself has 2 million rows.

And I have removed Index from **WIN** column which is of type `varchar`.

How can I speed this up?

Update:

TO let you know, I have around 2 million update queries like the one above with different values.

```
 UPDATE table1 
    SET WIN = 'A-9-0-9999-00000-00000-0000' 
    WHERE WIN= 'A-0-9-0000-999999-000000'

.

.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
 UPDATE table1 
    SET WIN = 'G-6-H-9999-00000-00000-0000' 
    WHERE WIN= 'A-1-9-0000-999999-000000'
```

and I am running all at once.

Comment: update in batches

Comment: @MitchWheat how? Example please. Since I am very new to this.

Comment: if somehow You can store old WIN value and New Win value in a table for all rows then You can Join a new table with Table1 and can update in a single go.

Comment: I already have 2 million rows of update queries in sql window. Is that a batch too? If yes, then that's taking time.

Comment: @MukeshArora that would take some changes and time which we are running out of. That's the problem.

Comment: Show us your actual query with the `JOIN` then , @Monkeyguru . The above just updates 1 row (I assume) with 1 value,. not 2 million.

Comment: @Larnu: Have 2 million rows with different values.

Comment: *"Have 2 million rows with different values"* well yes... That's why i'm asking for your query where you perform a `JOIn` between the 2 tables; then we can show you how to put it into batches.

Comment: Do you mean that there are 2 million rows in the table and you are updating all of them to a different value with 2 million individual update statements? TBH A set based UPDATE of 2 million rows should likely be fast enough that you can get away without batching if a bit of blocking isn't a huge issue. You could also consider just inserting the 2 million rows to a new table as a minimally logged operation and switching

Comment: @Larnu 2 tables? sir, I do have 1 table only... table1 which has 2 million rows and all needs to be update and that's what I am doing ... just pasting the 2 million udpate queries.... and Execute and it's taking time.

Comment: are you running them all as separate standalone transactions at the moment?

Comment: @MartinSmith: yes..... 2 million rows in the table and you are updating all of them to a different value with 2 million individual update statements

Comment: If you're running 2 Million statements, *that's* why it's so slow.

Comment: And if they are as individual transactions you will be waiting for 2 million log flushes and commits. Even batching up the individual statements in batches with explicit transactions would give a good speed increase though slower than a set based multirow update

Comment: Also removing the index was a very bad idea as these are all individual statements so it will need to scan 2 million squared rows collectively (4 trillion)

Comment: @MartinSmith the index was removed by DBA a week ago for some other reasons.

Comment: If I create an index on WIN would it speed up?

Comment: Without it every one of your 2 million UPDATE statements needs to scan the entire 2 million rows to find the one to UPDATE. But ideally you would get away from this 2 million statements anyway. You should bulk insert the "old" and "new" values into a staging table that you can then use for set based update(s)

Comment: Let me try that .

Comment: FIrst let me try with update

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should convert your updates to inserts and execute it by batches.

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
SET NOCOUNT ON;

CREATE TABLE #Replaces  (
    ReplaceId INT      NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    OldWIN    CHAR(27) NOT NULL,
    NewWIN    CHAR(27) NOT NULL,
    TargetId  INT
);

INSERT INTO #Replaces (OldWIN, NewWIN)
VALUES('A-9-0-9999-00000-00000-0000', 'A-0-9-0000-999999-000000')
-- ...
-- ...
INSERT INTO #Replaces (OldWIN, NewWIN)
VALUES('G-6-H-9999-00000-00000-0000', 'A-1-9-0000-999999-000000')

-- Scan for Id in table1 once.
UPDATE Replaces
SET TargetId = table1.Id
FROM #Replaces AS Replaces
INNER JOIN table1 ON table1.WIN = Replaces.OldWIN

DECLARE @BATCH_SIZE INT = 500;

DECLARE @batch    TABLE (
    ReplaceId INT      NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    TargetId  INT      NOT NULL,
    NewWin    CHAR(27) NOT NULL
);
DECLARE @maxId    INT = 0;

WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO @batch (ReplaceId, TargetId, NewWIN)
        SELECT TOP (@BATCH_SIZE) ReplaceId, TargetId, NewWIN
        FROM #Replaces
        WHERE ReplaceId > @maxId
        ORDER BY ReplaceId;

        IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 BREAK;

        UPDATE table1
        SET WIN = Batch.NewWin
        FROM @batch AS Batch
        INNER JOIN table1 ON table1.Id = Batch.TargetId

        SELECT @maxId = MAX(ReplaceId) FROM @batch;

        DELETE @batch;
    END TRY BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE = ERROR_MESSAGE();
        BREAK;
    END CATCH
END
```